# Point pattern matching invariant to scale and rotation, with possible deviations

Tags: computer-vision, pattern-matching, least-squares

In a computed vision problem, I have a detected set of points (2D coordinates of found objects) and a set of desired points (pattern, where the objects should be). The photo is genererally not rotated correctly, has dififerent scale than the desired points and some of the objects can be missing/not needed. The pattern is different for each photo, so I feel it would be useless to try learning any parameters of it.

I'm looking for a method (ideally implemented in a Python module) that could fit the desired points to those detected so that I would be able to find missing and not needed objects. It would probably be something based on the least squares method, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: Can you give an idea of the scale of the problem, in particular how many points you are talking about? For example would it be possible, given an image with p points, to try  to fit each p element subset of the desired points, or are there too many desired points to do that?

Comment: Are you saying that for each photo you are given the subset of desired points to match, or does the task include finding which subset is in the photo?

Comment: I know the desired points before detection. As for the scale, there may be 10-200 points in the desired set and probably a few more detections in most cases.

Comment: Ok. A tractable case is when you have, for a photo, a sequence of points p[0], p[1], ..  and a corresponding sequence of pattern points q[0], q[1].. By corresponding I mean that you know that p[0] and q[0] correspond, that p[1] and q[1] correspond and so on. You want to find the mapping that transforms each of the p[] to its corresponding q[]. This is known as the Procrustes problem. If this is the situation you are in I'll describe the method if you wish. The case where you just know that each p[i] corresponds to one of the q[], but don't know which, is more difficult.